# How to return IEnumerable DbSet in web api get?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

"user" classs auto generated by entity framework model first desinger.

```
public partial class user
{
    public user()
    {
        this.distributorDevice = new HashSet<distributorDevice>();
        this.managerDevice = new HashSet<managerDevice>();
        this.logUserLogin = new HashSet<logUserLogin>();
        this.logUserOperates = new HashSet<logUserOperates>();
        this.clientApp = new HashSet<clientApp>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public byte[] password { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime RegisterTime { get; set; }
    public int permissionId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime lastLoginTime { get; set; }

    public virtual permission permission { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<distributorDevice> distributorDevice { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<managerDevice> managerDevice { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<logUserLogin> logUserLogin { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<logUserOperates> logUserOperates { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<clientApp> clientApp { get; set; }
    public virtual customerDevice customerDevice { get; set; }
}
```

If I wrote like this

```
 public class UserController : ApiController
 {
 public IEnumerable<user> Get()
    {
        List<user> users = new List<user>();
        return user;
    }
 }
```

When I visit "localhost:3700/api/user" in explorer,it works.

```
<ArrayOfuser xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/UpdateServer.Model"/>
```

If I wrote like this

```
    public IEnumerable<user> Get()
    {
        using (var mydb = new ModelContainer())
        {
            return mydb.userSet.AsEnumerable();
        }
    }
```

When I visit "localhost:3700/api/user" in explorer, I get error message:

```
103 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED)
```

Follow advices, I should use ToList() instead of asEnumerable, I change code like this

```
using (var mydb = new ModelContainer())
        {
            var users = mydb.userSet.ToList();
            return users;
        }
```

but still same error comes in explorer

```
103 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED)
```

and I add a interrupt at

```
return users;
```

find that users already get the data from DB, but not correctly return to the client.

I do more test, I add an user with permission name "Admin", if I use code below, there is no user found, and it response to client correctly.

```
var users = mydb.userSet.Where(p=>p.permission.name == "Administrator").ToList();
return users;
```

if I write like this

```
var users = mydb.userSet.Where(p=>p.permission.name == "Admin").ToList();
return users;
```

it failed to return to client, give error

```
103 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED)
```

Comment: thanks, I use ToList() instead of AsEnumerable(), still not work.

Comment: Do you have any navigation property used, I yes you ave to eager load them ?

Comment: thanks,when I delete navigation property,it works. After some google on how to deal with it, I found that I should add DTO layers. Then new question comes. Many writers say that POCO is good than DTO, but I think DbContext is POCO, So I should use DTO+POCO? or I'm totally on the wrong way. Is there a way to only use DbcontextAPI?

Comment: imho the most important is to perfectly control the scope of your database context. DTO is one way, the school way, to achieve that control. Always imho, a POCO is a type/class allowing to instanciate an object. An object (instance of the POCO class) can be an entity related to the database context or a DTO not related (detached) from the database context. You have to drive the transition from entity to DTO, using or not the same type/class.

Answer (score 2):

EF uses lazy loading.  This means EF wont actually make a call to the database until you attempt to use the results.

To get around this you can use [ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb342261.aspx).  Unlike [AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb335435.aspx) ToList will instantly execute the query.

The other option is to not dispose the context.  Although this might seem wrong you can actually leave db context alive and let the Garbage collector get it when your no longer using any of the returned user objects.

Comment: thanks, I use ToList() instead of AsEnumerable(), still not work.

Comment: Leaving the db context open until garbage collection is an excellent way to exhaust your connection pool.

Comment: Also, `ToList` completely negates the performance benefit of exposing the `IQueryable` in the first place...